# LINQ to SQL where in (lambda syntax)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Can someone help me with this please?  I would like a simple 'where in'.  Here's the SQL that does what I want.

```
select ur.RoleID
from UserRoles ur
where ur.RoleID in (5, 15)
```

And here's my attempt.  The method .IN() doesn't exist obviously, just put my aggrevated thoughts lol.

```
int roleid;
foreach (data r in dataList) {
    using (DataContext communityContext = new DataContext()) {
        roleid = communityContext.UserRoles
            .Where(x => x.UserID == r.ClientId && x.RoleID.IN(5, 15))
            .Select(x => x.RoleID)
            .First();
    }
}
```

Comment: This comes up a lot. I feel like the .NET team should just create an extension method alias for `In()` that corresponds to `Contains()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mention `In` doesn't exist, se `.Contains()` instead if you have a list, in your case you could also use `x.RoleId == 5 || x.RoleId == 15`

e.g.

```
var allowedRoles = new int[] { 5, 15 };
```

then in your `where` clause do:

```
allowedRoles.Contains(x.RoleID)
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that ADO.NET Entity framework does not support .Contains - but there is a solution floating around on the net for a custom extension method that lets you still do it with linq to entity.

Answer (score 1):

```
var setNumbers = new List<int>() { 5, 15};

communityContext.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserID == r.ClientId)
                          .Where(x => setNumbers.Contains( x.RoleID ) )
                          ...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as...

```
int roleid;
var allowedRoles = new[] {5, 15};
foreach (data r in dataList) {
    using (DataContext communityContext = new DataContext()) {
        roleid = communityContext.UserRoles
            .First(x=> x.UserID == r.ClientId && allowedRoles.Contains(x.RoleID))
            .RoleID;            
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are creating the datacontext inside the loop.  That seems wasteful since the datacontext isn't dependent on the datalist.

Comment: Why would you put first in the beginning instead of the end?

Comment: you can't do a select() on a first()

Comment: oops.  typed it in the wrong order. sorry. That's what happens when you aren't paying attention.  fixed.